# HTML textareas - how to completely exclude from tabindex?

Tags: jquery, html, mobile-safari

I have 3 textareas. The first is the most normal one, it's part of an actual `<form>`, it's editable, etc. The other two are special use cases - you click/tap them and their contents are highlighted so you can Copy them (think "content extraction", not "user input"). So these 2 textareas can't link to each other or to the main textarea.

I found one solution, which is to set the tabindex of each textarea to a negative value. Problem is, on Mobile Safari, the "Previous" & "Next" buttons above the on-screen keyboard are active and the 2 oddball textareas end up being one-way paths to the main textarea when no tabindex value is applied to the main textarea; when there is a tabindex value applied to the main textarea, the odd behavior is harder to describe.

How can I get my 3 textareas to pretend they don't exist on the same page?! And please don't suggest iFrames, it's actually a PhoneGap app... A jQuery solution would be nice!

Comment: Why do you have the two other areas as `textarea` elements if they are not for user input?

Comment: Because when the user clicks/taps them, the user needs to be shown the "Copy" option. Unfortunately when you see "Click to Copy" on sites, that's actually using Flash & there is no JS method for copying to clipboard on modern browsers. It's a neat workaround that actually works, but yeah, they have to be textareas to bring up the keyboard & prompt for a Copy.

Comment: What? On any normal browser, when I triple click on a `div` element, then right-click, a get a Copy option. Just as with `textarea`. With both elements, double click selects the current word only. So please explain what you are really doing and what do you expect to achieve only by using `textarea`.

Comment: Forget about "normal" browsers, I'm talking exclusively about Mobile Safari (and presumably Android). When the user taps on the textarea, there's javascript that selects from character 0 to 99999, essentially selecting everything in the textarea. The idea is to get the user to the Copy option as easily as possible.

Comment: So what is this “javascript” that you are talking about, and why can’t you code a select operation for a `div` element? You should disclose all the relevant code in the question, and ask about desired functionality, not about assumed ”tabindex” behavior.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but - clearly we have different ideas of what's relevant to the question - I promise the JS was irrelevant and the reason I had to use a textarea instead of a regular `div` is that I didn't want any room for the user to give up, or not understand their device well enough to figure out the "hold to copy" concept. My solution is just tap & copy, instead of tap, hold, and copy. Anyway, the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the items with tabindex in a form, and add the two textarea excluded.

```
<form>
    <input />
    <input />
    <input />
</form>
<textarea />
<textarea />
```

Comment: Thanks but the textareas were already outside of the main `<form>`.

Answer (score 0):

Both textareas needed to be outside the main `<form>` and the other `textrea`'s needed to have negative tabindex values. I thought the keyboard on iOS could be shown on hybrid/web apps without the "Done"/Prev/Next bar that hovers over the keyboard, but apparently that's shown on all keyboards even when the form element you're focused on is the only one on the page - it's necessary because Apple can't trust/assume that the page is hiding the keyboard when it should. Comment here if you're aware of a way to disable that bar on PhoneGap!